# C - Why does this function not reverse the array?

Tags: c, arrays, reverse, heap-memory

This function should reverse an array of vectors on the heap, but it doesn't work. It seems like the tmp_array also gets changed.

Output is: 
13.700000 21.300000 
13.700000 21.300000

Should be:
8.900000 31.700000
13.700000 21.300000

createVector creates a struct Vector with two double values x and y.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _Vector_
{
    double x_;
    double y_;
} Vector;

Vector *createVector(double x, double y)
{
    Vector *vector = malloc((size_t)(sizeof(Vector)));
    if (vector == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Error!\n");
        return vector;
    }

    vector->x_ = x;
    vector->y_ = y;

    return vector;
}
void reverseVectorArray(Vector **vector_array, int length)
{
    Vector **tmp_array = malloc(sizeof(Vector*)*length);

    if(tmp_array == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Error!\n");
        return;
    }

    memcpy(tmp_array, vector_array, sizeof(Vector*)*length);

    int position = length - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        *(vector_array[position]) = *(tmp_array[i]);
        position--;
    }

    free(tmp_array);
}

int main()
{
    int length = 2;
    Vector **vector_array = malloc(sizeof(Vector*) * 2);
    vector_array[0] = createVector(13.7, 21.3);
    vector_array[1] = createVector(8.9, 31.7);

    reverseVectorArray(vector_array, length);

    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        printf("%f ", vector_array[i]->x_);
        printf("%f ", vector_array[i]->y_);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `Vector`? What is an example input/output of the function?

Comment: its a two-dimensional vector with two float values x and y.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Asterisks don't add up. `Vector **tmp_array` two asterisks. `malloc(sizeof(Vector)*length);` one asterisk. Wrong! Must be the same number. *its a two-dimensional vector with two float values x and y* is a load of words that are too vague if you don't see the relevant C declaration, and are completely useless if you do see one.

Comment: The program normally doesn't produce any output. How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and insert **all** relevant details into the question itself. Make sure your example is **complete**, i.e. one should be able to copy your code and compile and run it **as is**.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Okay, this seems to be a complete example. Thanks.

Now, first you should enable compiler warnings. The warnings will tell you to include `string.h`.

Then you should follow @n.m. 's advice and check where you have a Vector, a pointer to a Vector, and a pointer to a pointer to a Vector.

Comment: updatet it, no warnings, still doesn't work

Comment: After your edit, you have a problem in `createVector`, i.e. `Vector *vector = malloc((size_t)(sizeof(Vector*)));` --> `Vector *vector = malloc((size_t)(sizeof(Vector)));` - That is remove a *

Comment: When you count asterisks in malloc and you only allocate one object, you should always imagine there is `sizeof(...)*1` in there, otherwise the method won't work. Sorry I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Vector
{
    double x;
    double y;
} Vector;

Vector * createVector( double x, double y )
{
    Vector *vector = malloc( sizeof( Vector ) );

    if ( vector )
    {
        vector->x = x;
        vector->y = y;
    }

    return vector;
}

void reverseVectorArray( Vector **vector_array, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        Vector tmp = *vector_array[i];
        *vector_array[i] = *vector_array[n - i - 1];
        *vector_array[n - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    size_t n = 2;

    Vector **vector_array = malloc( n * sizeof( Vector * ) );

    vector_array[0] = createVector( 13.7, 21.3 );
    vector_array[1] = createVector( 8.9, 31.7 );

    reverseVectorArray( vector_array, n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%f ", vector_array[i]->x );
        printf( "%f ", vector_array[i]->y );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that you should append the program with a code that will free all allocated memory.

As for your code then for starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

If you are using the function `memcpy` then you need to include header `<string.h>`.

Instead of this declaration

```
Vector *vector = malloc((size_t)(sizeof(Vector*)));
                                        ^^^^^^^
```

you have to write

```
Vector *vector = malloc( sizeof( Vector ) );
                                 ^^^^^^
```

There is no need to allocate an auxiliary array to reverse the original array. Such an approach is inefficient.

The problem with your function `reverseVectorArray` is that it rewrites the values of the second half of the array with the values of the first half of the array. So it makes two halves of the array equal each other.

Comment: I think it would be sufficient to swap the pointers instead of copying the structs

Comment: @4386427 It depends on the design of the program.